# overwriting list keyword in python

Tags: python

I coded a short linked list program in Python, but without realizing list was a keyword in python, I stored my `LinkedList` object into list

```
list = LinkedList()
```

Running this program worked fine, but now I'm running into issues in another program where I need the list keyword to be used normally, but it still contains a reference to the `LinkedList` object and not the proper keyword functionality. I have since gone back to my `LinkedList` class and edited `list` to be `lst` instead, but I still have the same error in the class that uses the list keyword. How do I reset the list keyword to its original value?

This is the line that is giving me an error:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(6,4), index = dates, columns = list("ABCD"))
```

And this is the error message:

> TypeError: 'LinkedList' object is not callable

Comment: can you show the actual error?

Comment: Don't use `list` in the first place. Use some other name which is more descriptive. If you removed all instances of `list = #something` then there should be no errors. Show us your stack trace.

Comment: You know... *"I've overridden a keyword"* kind of problems really have an obvious solution... at least for practical applications. Good academical question though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally overwriting a builtin is not ideal and you can use `del` or `__builtins__` to fix it.

Using `del` to reset it:

```
>>> list = '1,2,3'
>>> list
'1,2,3'
>>> del list
>>> list
<type 'list'>
```

Using `__builtins__.list` to reset it.

```
>>> list = '1,2,3'
>>> list
'1,2,3'
>>> list = __builtins__.list
>>> list
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: Got a random notification for this question I asked years ago. I don't remember the situation entirely, but I was definitely working in a notebook and not just running a program normally, so this solution would be the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's almost certainly better to stop shadowing builtins, as Kroltan says in his comment, but [as the Python quote goes](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-October/025932.html)

> we are all consenting adults here

so…

```
>>> list='axe'
>>> __builtins__.list('abc')
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Also, for fun, you can convert a literal to its type function using the `type` function.

```
>>> list='chuck testa'
>>> type([])('abc')
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> type(3)(10.5)
10
```

etc